# When is a Docker Service Considered to be Running?

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

I am working on a debian based container which runs a c++ compiled application as a child process to a node.js script.  For testing, I am attempting to define a swarm that instantiates this container as a service.  When I run "docker service ls", it reports that the service is no running.  If I issue "docker ps", however, I can see the identifier for the container and I can use "docker exec" to connect to it.

So far as I can see, the two target processes are running within the container yet, when other containers within the same swarm and using the same networks attempt to connect to this server, I see a name resolution error.

Here is my question:  If the intended processes are actively and verifiably running within a container, why would docker consider a service based on that container to not be running?  What is Docker's criteria for considering a container to be running as a service?

Comment: Did you mean `docker service ps` which lists the tasks associated with the service?  Because `docker service ls` just lists the services.

Comment: I was not aware of docker service ps.  When i run that command, the current state is reported as starting.  When does docker consider the task to be running?  As an aside, I just found that, if I am less impatient, eventually docker reports the service as running.  I just don't know why it is taking so long...

Comment: Does your Dockerfile have a `HEALTHCHECK` directive?

Comment: The dockerfile does not have HEALTHCHECK but the stack yml file does.  So is docker waiting for the container tpo pass its health ccheck (15 minutes) before the service is considered to be running?

Comment: AFAIK, yes, it's waiting for the healthcheck.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand.  I think that little bit will get me where  I need to go.  If you would like to write up your responses as an answer, I would be delighted to upvote it and mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status of `starting` means that it's waiting for the [`HEALTHCHECK`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) condition to be satisfied.

Examine your Dockerfile's (or compose file's) `HEALTHCHECK` conditions and investigate why they are not being satisfied.

NOTE: Do not confuse `starting` with **`restarting`**, which means that the program is being launched again (usually after a crash) due to the restart policy.